# Updating a chart with new data every 2 seconds

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Here is my angular controller with a service call for my json data.

```
.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope, jsondata, $interval,  $timeout) {
    var _this = this;
    jsondata.getJsonData().then(function(data) {
        $scope.items = _this.items;
    var oneArray = _this.items.map(function(v) {
      return v.id1;
    });
   var twoArray = _this.items.map(function(v) {
      return v.id2;
    });



      **$scope.data = [
        oneArray
      ];**
  });
});
```

This works just well. But what I want to do is change the chart data every two seconds between oneArray and twoArray. And I want it to be infinite ... just switching between the two data arrays making some sort of a real time effect.

Comment: Can you provide a Jsfiddle link?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use "setInterval" in your case, try to do a thing similar like this:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http, $timeout) {

  // Function to get the data
  $scope.getData = function(){
    $http.get('style.css')
      .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

      // Your code here
      console.log('Fetched data!');
    });
  };

  // Function to replicate setInterval using $timeout service.
  $scope.intervalFunction = function(){
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.getData();
      $scope.intervalFunction();
    }, 1000)
  };

  // Kick off the interval
  $scope.intervalFunction();

});
```

Comment: Hi @ruslan I am using an angular service outside my controller to get the data. So I guess am not using getData as you have done with angular $http.

Comment: It peddling at the end, how you obtain data.I see that you use promises to obtain data from external service, when you go to resolve those promises (in your case is "jsondata.getJsonData().then(function(data) { // do something }) you need to notify the scope that something is changed to do this use $scope.$apply()